# I can't seem to figure out how to stop my html form from splitting apart and shifting down when resizing the page

Tags: html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, capistrano3

I'm working on a rails application and I keep having this problem where my html form keeps splitting apart and moving down every time I resize the page. I have tried wrapping it in  tags, trying different positions, floats, and displays and nothing seems to work. Currently, this is my code for it. Also, I have some images of the outcome.

How would you go about preventing this from happening? This happens both in a production and development environment, if that changes anything.

html:

```
<div id="containerc">
  <div id="contcontent">
    <div id="formwrapper">
      <form action="/contacts" method="POST">
        <label for="fullname" class="label" id="fullname">Full Name*</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="input" id="ifullname" style="width: 48.5vw; height: 2.5vw; font-size: 1.5vw;" />
        <label class="label" id="email" for="email">Email*</label>
        <input id="iemail" type="text" name="email" class="input" style="font-size: 
                              1.5vw; width: 48.5vw; height: 2.5vw;" />
        <label for="company" class="label" id="company">Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" class="input" id="icompany" style="width: 
                              48.5vw; height: 2.5vw; font-size: 1.5vw;" />
        <label for="message" class="label" id="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="imessage" name="message" class="input" style="width: 48.5vw; 
                              height: 8vw; font-size: 1.2vw;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 10vw; height: 
                              2vw;" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
h1#cont {
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 31vw;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 7vw;
  left: 32.3vw;
  font-family: albaregular;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label#fullname.label {
  font-family: eb_garamond_sc08_regular;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25.4vw;
  bottom: -20vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

label#email.label {
  font-family: eb_garamond_sc08_regular;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25.4vw;
  bottom: -26vw;
  z-index: 7;
}

label#company.label {
  font-family: eb_garamond_sc08_regular;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25.4vw;
  bottom: -32vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

label#message.label {
  font-family: eb_garamond_sc08_regular;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25.4vw;
  bottom: -38vw;
  z-index: 4;
}

input#ifullname.input {
  left: 25.3vw;
  bottom: -23vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

input#iemail.input {
  left: 25.3vw;
  bottom: -29vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

input#icompany.input {
  left: 25.3vw;
  bottom: -35vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

textarea.input {
  left: 25.3vw;
  bottom: -46.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

input#submit {
  left: 43vw;
  font-size: 1vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -52vw;
  font-family: eb_garamond_sc08_regular;
}
```

Images:

[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiDLa.png)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFtP5.png)

Comment: Not sure if this causes the issue (although it is likely), but either way, you probably shouldn't use `position: absolute` on every single element. For one, it's very tedious to manually place each element and consider how difficult it would be to add a field in the middle. Second, it's error prone and likely will produce different results on different screen sizes. Instead maybe consider using some CSS layout displays like [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Comment: You problem is not reproducible with only the code provided (copy only the html and css into some file or use e. g. https://codepen.io/). Generally, since your page structure is very simple, I'd recommend removing any form of `position`'ing, and instead only use `div`s or `display: block` to archive the column layout. Also keep all your styles in css, instead of `style`-attributes.

Comment: It honey might. I'm very new to html/css so I don't fully know which one to use and when. The problem is that when I use relative everything messes up even more. Also would I just remove position altogether and replace it with flex? Wouldn't that prevent me from being able to move it around the screen? I now see I can just move the form without moving everything in it but still no matter the position I use it always seems to mess up.

Comment: @Reizo damn it's not? That sucks. That being said how would I position a form where I want it to be on the page without using position: ...;? As in if I want it to be where it is on the fullscreen image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your HTML and removed all the positioning and only used a wrapper `div` centering the entire form with

```
display: grid;
place-items: center;
```

and aligned the form elements in a column using

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

on the `form`.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 1vw; /* questionable from a design perspective */
}

input,
textarea {
  font-size: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="form" action="/contacts" method="POST">
    <label for="ifullname" class="label" id="fullname">Full Name*</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" class="input" id="ifullname"/>
    <label class="label" id="email" for="iemail">Email*</label>
    <input id="iemail" type="text" name="email" class="input"/>
    <label for="icompany" class="label" id="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" name="company" class="input" id="icompany"/>
    <label class="label" for="imessage" class="label" id="message">Message</label>
    <textarea id="imessage" name="message" class="input"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

As long as your layout stays rather simple, you should use that template as a base and maybe only use some different padding or adjust font size if you prefer so...

Also note that in `label`'s `for` you need to specify the referred `input`'s `id` instead of `name` to work properly.

Comment: that was totally it! Thank you so much! I also understand better what I did wrong so thank you for your help.